# AWS: Route 53 Configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have created two instances in AWS (one is Live & other is Backup). My website is hosted on Live Instance. I have configured Route 53, Health checks & Hosted zones on default settings. Also have added both Instances to load balancer, and the status is "InService" for both the Instances.

For the Live Instance, Public IP & Elastic IP are the same. For Backup Instance, Public IP is different from live, and Elastic IP is null.

What I want to achieve is, when my Live Instance "status check" or "Health check" fails, then Backup Instance should get activated.

Currently when I manually stop my Live Instance for testing purpose, the backup Instance should get activated. but it doesn't. Please let me know if I am missing any steps.

Comment: I believe you will find that [cross-posting to Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/questions/718577/aws-route-53-configuration) is discouraged.  The question should be posted on the most appropriate site (only).

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a healthcheck REST API that ELB can call. Your backup instance can return a non-200 HTTP status. The moment it is activated it starts return HTTP 200. This will tell ELB to only route calls to the primary.

Meanwhile, your Route53 should point at the ELB, not directly at the instances.

Generally speaking, however, you want to keep both primary and backup instances hot for optimal performance and failover. You can get the best of AWS advantages if you don't rely on your instances to be in a particular state -- primary vs backup in this case. I would devise a strategy to keep both instances in use.